# Which is the compatible version of IEDriverServer for IE11 and Selenium 3.13?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

I am automating tests with IE11 and Selenium 3.13 and I was testing different version of `IEDriverServer` but every version has a bug. I want a stable version to combine `IEDriverServer` with IE11 and Selenium 3.13

I'm using this code to launch the application:

```
private static WebDriver setRemoteDriver(Map<String, Object> selConfig) {
    String browser = System.getProperty("browser", selConfig.get("browser").toString());
    capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("firefox")) {
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        capabilities.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE, getFirefoxProfile());
        capabilities.setCapability("pageLoadStrategy", "normal");
    } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("Safari")) {
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.safari();
    } else if ((browser.equalsIgnoreCase("ie")) || (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("internetexplorer"))
            || (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("internet explorer"))) {
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Please correct Browser specify in YAML file : " + browser);
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    }
    try {
        url = new URL(System.getProperty("ipaddress", getYamlValue("selenium.remote.host")));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new RemoteWebDriver(url, capabilities);
}
```

Comment: what issue/exception you are facing, also use Options instead of desired capabilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IEDriverServer** for **IE11** and **Selenium** should always be identical.
As per best practices you should always use the recent GA version while some organizations tends to prefer the major GA releases only.

As an example:

- For *Selenium v3.14.0* you should always use *IEDriverServer v3.14.0*

[image: selenium_3_14_0]

---

- In some exceptional cases there may be minor *Selenium* releases where you need to use the *IEDriverServer* from the major release. As an example:

  - For *Selenium v3.141.0*, *Selenium v3.141.5* and *Selenium v3.141.59* you should always use *IEDriverServer v3.141.0* only.

[image: selenium_3_141_0]

---

### This Usecase

For *Selenium v3.13.0* you should always use *IEDriverServer v3.13.0*

[image: selenium_3_13_0]

Comment: This is absolutely and entirely untrue. The nature of WebDriver makes it possible to have mixed versions. While it might be preferable to keep versions in sync, and “best practice” may say to always use the latest, there are times it might be beneficial to mix versions.

Comment: @JimEvans Can you please shed some light on this question. AFAIK, **IEDriverServer** on its own doesn't have a release notes to refer/fallback even. Can you help us out?

Comment: the version of driver work I can launch a browser and login to the APP but there is some element inside the frame how selenium can't access and I have this error :org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with css selector == #destinataire
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: I am using switch to frame and script work fine with chrome and FF

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer valid any idea!!!

Comment: @DebanjanB There is [a CHANGELOG](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/cpp/iedriverserver/CHANGELOG) that is current for every release of the IE driver, even those not released publicly as a point-release. Every. Single. Release. This is as it has been for several _years_ on the project, and is not new information. From there, it’s easy to determine which version might be appropriate, and it might well be independent of the language bindings’ version.

Comment: @JimEvans Thanks for sharing this useful information.