# org.apache.bcel.verifier.exc.AssertionViolatedException.main(AssertionViolatedException.java:102) error with Selenium and Java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to write an automated test and the code successfully compiles but when i try executing it as "Java Application", I am getting an `AssertionViolatedException` error and the code won't execute.

I have already tried:

1. Changing the `sendKeys("string")` to `sendKeys(new String[] {"string"})`.
2. Executing the application with: "Run as: JAVA APPLICATION"
3. Setting the jre environment in build path.

The error message I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.bcel.verifier.exc.AssertionViolatedException: 
FOUND:
    INTERNAL ERROR: Oops!
Exiting!!

at org.apache.bcel.verifier.exc.AssertionViolatedException.main(AssertionViolatedException.java:102)
```

Comment: You might as well add the code to your question, so from the looks of it it might not be necessarily related to that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.bcel.verifier.exc.AssertionViolatedException: 
FOUND:
    INTERNAL ERROR: Oops!
Exiting!!

at org.apache.bcel.verifier.exc.AssertionViolatedException.main(AssertionViolatedException.java:102)
```

...implies that there was a [*RuntimeException*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html?is-external=true) which should never be thrown and as per the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/verifier/exc/AssertionViolatedException.html) such exception is thrown due to an `INTERNAL ERROR` of BCEL's class file verifier **`JustIce`**.

This exception and error is defined as:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    AssertionViolatedException ave = new AssertionViolatedException("Oops!");
    ave.extendMessage("\nFOUND:\n\t","\nExiting!!\n");
    throw ave;
}
```

---

Your code trials would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. However this exception is thrown when BCEl tries to verify bytecode modifications and fails. Presumably you are using some jar(s)/tool(s) that uses BCEL to modify the bytecode your Java compiler generates. if you are using BCEL as a requirement you need to debug, why it breaks. If you are not using BCEL as a requirement you can try a either of the steps mentioned below:

- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* (`Project` > `Clean...` > `Clean all projects` > `OK`) and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Add *WebDriverWait* bofore invoking `sendKeys()` method as follows:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.nsg-button")))sendKeys("string");
  ```
- Create a fresh *New Project*, *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only and execute your *Tests*.

Comment: Hello Debanjan Could you please shed a little more light on what these jar(s)/tool(s) can be that may try to modify the bytecode? Perhaps give an example? Thanks

Comment: Hello Debenjan, I am also **not using BCEL as a requirement**. So it is probably the jar(s)/tool(s) can you help me identify which ones might be using BCEL for the modification of the bytecode?

Comment: @user11888730 _Clean up_ and induce _WebDriverWait_ first. The error may go away.

Comment: I tried doing this, but still getting the same error.

Comment: @user11888730 Can you create a fresh new project and try the same?

Comment: After a deeper research, it seems that the project is unable to find the WebDriver. Should I create a fresh project for the same ?

Comment: @user11888730 Yes, that would be a better approach.

Comment: Can you tell me what version of IEDriverServer is compatible with Selenium 3.14.0?

Comment: @user11888730 Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53929340/which-is-the-compatible-version-of-iedriverserver-for-ie11-and-selenium-3-13/53932187#53932187) helps you?

Comment: Yes it does! Thank you for your help !